# Are there method references to the base math functions?

Tags: java, method-reference

For example, I can specify `Math::cbrt` to tell the lambda to take the cube root of the value.

Can I refer to multiplication and division functions using method references?

Obviously I can make my own lambda but it would be nice to have consistency.

Comment: You mean like `IntBinaryOperator op = Math::multiplyExact;`?

Comment: _Are there method references [...]?_  Method references can exist for anything, in the appropriate _context_.

Comment: @Tunaki - No - like `Double y = x * Math.Pi;` but using method references.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Not sure I understand. The method-reference would refer to `multiplyExact`. And you apply that on some values. But if what you mean is to refer to `*`, then I don't think there's a built-in for that.

Comment: There has to be a method for there to be a method reference.

Comment: It sounds a bit like you want something similar to the `operator` module in python.  Don't know if Java provides one, but it would be interesting to see if it did.

Comment: @Tunaki - `MultiplyExact` takes `(int,int)`. I want something like `Math::multiply` just like `Math::cbrt`.

Comment: Then I think you need to make your own. There is `Double::sum` for the plus operation but that's it. It's pretty straight-forward: `public static double multiply(double a, double b) { return a * b; }`. And then you can refer to that method.

Comment: There isn't one in the library, as the default operators don't have a method. You could always write your own `PiMultiplier implements DoubleBinaryOperator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) *There has to be a method for there to be a method reference.*

And - since there aren't methods to do `x * y` (except perhaps in `BigInteger`) the answer is **there are no method references to the in-line math functions**.